# xtable output for a list of tables

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

I've a list of tables and want to sweave it for LaTex output. Here is the code:

```
Data <- esoph[ , 1:3]
library(plyr)
combos <- combn(ncol(Data),2)

TabelFn <- function(x) {
  Table <- addmargins(table(Data[, x[1]], Data[, x[2]]))
  return(Table)
  }

Table <- alply(.data=combos, .margins=2, .fun=TabelFn, .expand=TRUE)
library(xtable)
```

The list `Table` has three contingency tables in this case and I can sweave the output to LaTex using this code:

```
<< label = tabTable, echo = FALSE, results = tex >>=
print(xtable(Table[1]$'1', caption = "Contingency table for agegp and alcgp", label = "tab:Table[1]",
             digits = c(0, rep(0, ncol(Table[1]$'1'))),
             align = paste(paste("l|", paste(rep("r", ncol(Table[1]$'1')-1), collapse =     ''), sep = ""), "l", sep = "")),
      table.placement = "tbp", caption.placement = "top",
      hline.after = c(-1, 0, nrow(Table[1]$'1')))
@
```

To send the output of three contingency tables I've to write three such commands. In this case it is feasible. But for my actual data I've many contingency tables. I'd like to know how to send all contingency tables more efficiently. One choice is to just print the list `Table` without `xtable`. But I'd like to have the contingency table in nice output format. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed some mock data to work with

```
Data <- data.frame(a=rbinom(100,1,0.5), b=rbinom(100,1,0.3), c=rbinom(100,1,0.6))
```

With your code to generate `Table`, this will get you close

```
l_ply(Table, function(TBL) {
  print(xtable(TBL, 
      caption = "Contingency table for agegp and alcgp", #This information is not in the TBL anywhere
      label = "tab:Table[1]", # This is also problematic
      digits = c(0, rep(0, ncol(TBL))),
    align = paste(paste("l|", paste(rep("r", ncol(TBL)-1), collapse = ''), sep = ""), "l", sep = "")),
    table.placement = "tbp",
    caption.placement = "top",
    hline.after = c(-1, 0, nrow(TBL)))  
})
```

You can get the label right by iterating over an index of `Table` rather than `Table` itself

```
a_ply(seq_along(Table), 1, function(i) {
  print(xtable(Table[[i]], 
      caption = "Contingency table for agegp and alcgp", #This information is not in the Table[[i]] anywhere
      label = paste("tab:Table[",i,"]",sep=""), 
      digits = c(0, rep(0, ncol(Table[[i]]))),
    align = paste(paste("l|", paste(rep("r", ncol(Table[[i]])-1), collapse = ''), sep = ""), "l", sep = "")),
    table.placement = "tbp",
    caption.placement = "top",
    hline.after = c(-1, 0, nrow(Table[[i]])))       
})
```

The caption can not be made automatically because the information is not there.  However, if you modify your `TableFn` function, you can add that information and then extract it back out.

```
TabelFn <- function(x) {
  Table <- addmargins(table(Data[, x[1]], Data[, x[2]]))
  names(attr(Table,"dimnames")) <- names(Data)[x]
  return(Table)
}

Table <- alply(.data=combos, .margins=2, .fun=TabelFn, .expand=TRUE)

a_ply(seq_along(Table), 1, function(i) {
  vars <- names(attr(Table[[i]],"dimnames"))
  print(xtable(Table[[i]], 
      caption = paste("Contingency table for", vars[1], "and", vars[2]),
      label = paste("tab:Table[",i,"]",sep=""), # This is also problematic
      digits = c(0, rep(0, ncol(Table[[i]]))),
    align = paste(paste("l|", paste(rep("r", ncol(Table[[i]])-1), collapse = ''), sep = ""), "l", sep = "")),
    table.placement = "tbp",
    caption.placement = "top",
    hline.after = c(-1, 0, nrow(Table[[i]])))       
})
```

Comment: @ Brian Diggs, Thanks a lot. You always come to save me. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Brian Diggs, I'd highly appreciate if you help me to get the Frequencies in the same way. I used this command Freq <- alply(.data=Data, .margins=2, .fun=table, .expand=TRUE) and unable to assign names. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With few variables this works fine. But with my actual data I'm getting LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floa
ts.

Comment: @MYaseen208: For frequency, I'd do it a little differently. `Freq <- llply(.data=Data, .fun=table)` (this uses the fact that a `data.frame` is a list of columns and pulls the column names in) and then `xtable`-ing it by iterating over the names: `l_ply(names(Freq), function(n) {print(xtable(Freq[[n]], caption=n))})` (I've left out most of the formatting for space, but the caption is there).

Comment: Regarding the too many unprocessed floats, perhaps try changing the `table.placement` to `H` and adding `\usepackage{float}` to the preamble of the Sweave file.  I don't know if it will work, but it might.

Comment: I used both ' \usepackage{float} ' and ' \usepackage[maxfloats=100]{morefloats} ' but still I've the same error. Anyhow thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Given the absence of actual data and its structure, here is one approach.

```
TabelFn2 <- function(x) {
  Table <- addmargins(table(Data[, x[1]], Data[, x[2]]))
  print(xtable(Table$'1', caption = "Contingency table for agegp and alcgp", 
       label = "tab:Table", digits = c(0, rep(0, ncol(Table$'1'))),
       align = paste(paste("l|", paste(rep("r", ncol(Table$'1')-1), 
       collapse = ''), sep = ""), "l", sep = "")),
      table.placement = "tbp", caption.placement = "top",
      hline.after = c(-1, 0, nrow(Table$'1')))
 }

<<echo = F, results = tex>>=
a_ply(.data=combos, .margins=2, .fun=TabelFn2)
@
```

Comment: @ Ramnath for your reply. Using your given code Rnw file works but with LaTex I got this error message: LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats. Even I used \usepackage[section] {placeins}. Any comment. Thanks again.